# Difference in openssl implementation while testing ssl/tls version support

Tags: openssl

I am trying to test tls/ssl version support using `openssl`. I see there is difference in result in 3 different versions of OpenSSL.

**OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014:** Please note that in this case I am able to make a connection using openssl and even able to test ssl2, tls1 etc. but below output only comes when trying to test ssl3. So, I am not able to understand the behavior.

```
C:\Users\himanshu.agrawal>openssl s_client -connect facebook.com:443 -ssl3
WARNING: can't open config file: /apache24/conf/openssl.cnf
unknown option -ssl3
usage: s_client args

 -host host     - use -connect instead
 -port port     - use -connect instead
 -connect host:port - who to connect to (default is localhost:4433)
 -verify arg   - turn on peer certificate verification
 -verify_return_error - return verification errors
 -cert arg     - certificate file to use, PEM format assumed
 -certform arg - certificate format (PEM or DER) PEM default
 -key arg      - Private key file to use, in cert file if
                 not specified but cert file is.
 -keyform arg  - key format (PEM or DER) PEM default
 -pass arg     - private key file pass phrase source
 -CApath arg   - PEM format directory of CA's
 -CAfile arg   - PEM format file of CA's
 -reconnect    - Drop and re-make the connection with the same Session-ID
 -pause        - sleep(1) after each read(2) and write(2) system call
 -prexit       - print session information even on connection failure
 -showcerts    - show all certificates in the chain
 -debug        - extra output
 -msg          - Show protocol messages
 -nbio_test    - more ssl protocol testing
 -state        - print the 'ssl' states
 -nbio         - Run with non-blocking IO
 -crlf         - convert LF from terminal into CRLF
 -quiet        - no s_client output
 -ign_eof      - ignore input eof (default when -quiet)
 -no_ign_eof   - don't ignore input eof
 -psk_identity arg - PSK identity
 -psk arg      - PSK in hex (without 0x)
 -srpuser user     - SRP authentification for 'user'
 -srppass arg      - password for 'user'
 -srp_lateuser     - SRP username into second ClientHello message
 -srp_moregroups   - Tolerate other than the known g N values.
 -srp_strength int - minimal mength in bits for N (default 1024).
 -ssl2         - just use SSLv2
 -ssl3         - just use SSLv3
 -tls1_2       - just use TLSv1.2
 -tls1_1       - just use TLSv1.1
 -tls1         - just use TLSv1
 -dtls1        - just use DTLSv1
 -fallback_scsv - send TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV
 -mtu          - set the link layer MTU
 -no_tls1_2/-no_tls1_1/-no_tls1/-no_ssl3/-no_ssl2 - turn off that protocol
 -bugs         - Switch on all SSL implementation bug workarounds
 -serverpref   - Use server's cipher preferences (only SSLv2)
 -cipher       - preferred cipher to use, use the 'openssl ciphers'
                 command to see what is available
 -starttls prot - use the STARTTLS command before starting TLS
                 for those protocols that support it, where
                 'prot' defines which one to assume.  Currently,
                 only "smtp", "pop3", "imap", "ftp" and "xmpp"
                 are supported.
 -engine id    - Initialise and use the specified engine
 -rand file;file;...
 -sess_out arg - file to write SSL session to
 -sess_in arg  - file to read SSL session from
 -servername host  - Set TLS extension servername in ClientHello
 -tlsextdebug      - hex dump of all TLS extensions received
 -status           - request certificate status from server
 -no_ticket        - disable use of RFC4507bis session tickets
 -nextprotoneg arg - enable NPN extension, considering named protocols supported (comma-separated list)
 -legacy_renegotiation - enable use of legacy renegotiation (dangerous)
 -use_srtp profiles - Offer SRTP key management with a colon-separated profile list
 -keymatexport label   - Export keying material using label
 -keymatexportlen len  - Export len bytes of keying material (default 20)
```

**OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015**

```
$ openssl s_client -connect facebook.com:443 -ssl3
CONNECTED(00000003)
2282780:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1472:SSL alert number 40
2282780:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:656:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : SSLv3
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1449768766
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

**OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008:**
I know SSL3 is disabled in Facebook but interestingly I am getting a SSL connection established. But when I look closely then I see that server certificate is totally different. Actually this time I am running command on a remote box and that's a private network and I am connecting to it using VPN and then executing openssl command. Could something related to this.

Anybody has any idea or seen such differences, especially first 2.

Comment: Your first test failed to connect because it didn't support ssl3. _unknown option -ssl3_

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: SSLv3 was effectively switched off by everyone after [POODLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POODLE). Using the `-ssl3` option should fail just about everywhere.

Comment: M bad, I should have mentioned in my question that I am trying to develop a Java based SSL server debugger tool and I faced blah blah issue while trying to use following openssl command through Java programming but I thought to hit directly at the target so didn't.

Comment: @hagrawal - no problem. If you had taken the advice and gone to InfoSec.SE, you would likely already have an answer to the questions. The site's rules prohibit me from answering. You might also want to look up the definition of the word *plead*. It was not meant as an insult to you.